# DataTrigger on integer value 0 for TextBlock text doesn't work

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I have a `TextBlock` that displays the count of entries available in the view model. Now I try to format this count with `FontWeight` `Bold` if there are more than zero entries.

For simplicity (avoid the overhead of a `ValueConverter`) I reversed the logic and applied the default `FontWeight` of `Bold` to the TextBlock with trying to override this `FontWeight` via `DataTrigger`, if there are no entries.

But I'm afraid that this does not work, the count is displayed bold all the time:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Entries.Count, StringFormat=' [{0}]'}" FontWeight="Bold">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SharedNodeNames.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

(for testing purposes I removed the `StringFormat` part in the `TextBlock` `Text` binding, but this doesn't makes a difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default value of the `FontWeight` property in a `Style` setter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Entries.Count, StringFormat=' [{0}]'}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SharedNodeNames.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Local values take precedence over values set by styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Comment: This works, didn't know this, thank you!